# google map api in asp.net web forms display arabic characters as "?"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have put google map with JavaScript in my web form like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent("\u200e"+data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
}
```

I also have a script which loads markers from database and display them on the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers = [
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
            {
                "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',
            "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
            "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
            "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
        }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];
</script>
```

It is working OK, but the problem is that my description and name fields are in Persian language. This is output in which Arabic/Persian characters are being converted into "?" character. Any help to fix it?

[image: YU HA HA]

Answer (score 0):

to store Arabic letters in database you should define table columns as nvarchar(N) instead of varchar(N).